Can not query ".slds-modal__container" to resize the width in particular org
Hi I want to resize the modal width in quick action, so I have made this in connectedCallback:
    connectedCallback() {
        let modal = document.querySelectorAll(".slds-modal__container");
        if (modal && modal.length > 0 && modal[0].style.minWidth != "90rem") {
            modal[0].style.minWidth = "90rem";
        }
    }

I have 2 orgs: DEV and UAT. It works well on the DEV org. But on UAT, when debugging, I noticed that the document.querySelectorAll(".slds-modal__container") does not return any modal. Both of the orgs are having the same code with the API version 61.0. Can anyone help with this case? Thanks!
